# Using LogonUser() only to Validate Credentials

Tags: c++, windows, security, authentication, active-directory

We are developing an application with an internal user accounts system, but would like to be able to use credentials from Active Directory and/or Windows accounts. To that end we store the User SID in a field in the application's users table. Our login mechanism functions like this:

- Prompt user for domain, login, password
- Call [LogonUser(logon, domain, password, logon_type, logon_provider, &hToken)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- If successful, get User SID from hToken
- Close hToken
- Search our application's database for a user with the given SID; if found, we are considered logged in to that account.

The problem that has come up is this: we have been using LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK for the logon_type, but we have now run into some security configurations where "Access this computer from the network" is denied, meaning the Network logon type is prohibited.

My question is what logon type should we be using for this situation? Interactive? We are not actually using the Logon token for anything other than extracting the user's SID. Our application has its own internal groups and permissions; we do not use Windows groups or permissions in any way. From the perspective of Windows and the domain controller, all we are doing is logging on and quickly logging off.

Or are we looking at this in a completely wrong way, and we should be using some other login method entirely?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a desktop application or a web app? Why not use Kerberos to authenticate the user against AD?

Comment: Desktop. We've already written the login stuff and we're hoping to just have to change that one parameter.

Also we want to be able to use local Windows accounts in addition to AD.

Comment: Desktop?  So the user is already logged on?  Why does your application need them to log on again, why not just use the existing SID?  (More importantly, you do realize that the user will be able to easily bypass your logon mechanism and log into your application as any other user?)

Comment: The LogonUser call takes place in a service running on the SYSTEM account. I don't see how they would be able to spoof an SID without Admin rights on the computer.

Comment: Yes, if it's a service that's OK.  Jumping to conclusions there, sorry.  And since the user must be interactively logged on, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE is a perfectly sensible choice.  Note however that named pipes (and most other IPC mechanisms) allow you to determine the identity of the user without having to reauthenticate them.

Comment: In practice our application is often left open for long periods of time for monitoring purposes (which doesn't require a log-in). We want to force an explicit log-in for write operations. So we can't just use the current Windows session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have been surprised to find out that the `LogonUser()` with the `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK` type fails when user right "Access this computer from the network" is not granted for Everyone on **local computer**.

I use the following workaround:

- First try `LogonUser()` with the `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK` type.
- If it fails with error `ERROR_LOGON_TYPE_NOT_GRANTED`, call `LogonUser()` with the `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` type and the `LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50` logon provider.

Comment: This should work although it will have the side effect of using two login attempts, which is potentially undesirable in high-security networks with a low number of attempts before lockout. Probably saving a flag somewhere is a good idea so it only does this once.

Comment: Saving a flag is a good idea. I suppose the ERROR_LOGON_TYPE_NOT_GRANTED logon failure should not be accounted as failed log on by the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with the SSPI services to validate a user's credentials and acquire a token, without requiring special privileges. This requires a lot of obscure code and

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180548 for an example; the `SSPLogonUser` function is where the token is acquired.

Comment: Actually, on re-reading, I'm not sure if this will work for you. I'll leave the answer, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The convention is to use LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH, as documented:

> This logon type is intended for batch servers, where processes may be executing on behalf of a user without their direct intervention. **This type is also for higher performance servers that process many plaintext authentication attempts at a time, such as mail or web servers.**

(emphasis mine).

The system administrators may still need to reconfigure the server to grant batch logon access to the users in question, but because this does not grant the user access to any Windows functionality (e.g., the ability to use Remote Desktop, to connect to a network share, or to log on interactively if they somehow gain access to the console) this should not be a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not do, as this right is not granted on most systems. I think I will likely just stick with Interactive.

Comment: Most system administrators will be reluctant to allow end users to log on to a server interactively.